# How to get a txt file and compare it with array for a drop down list using webdriver/java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the scenario:

1) create a file with input string Sep 2015 2) Collect the drop down list into an array 3) if array equals to string(which is in that file) come out of loop else downloads new month report and overwrites the same text file with new month name.

We tried with string in the code, but didn't created a file(don't know how to link that txt file to code to check if the array equals to string and iteration has to happen).

Here is the code:

```
driver.get("http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report");
WebElement mSelectElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"));
List<WebElement> optionsList = mSelectElement.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

                String oldMonth = "";
                //if (optionsList.size() > 1) {
                    // Here considering first string from the optionsList(Here first
                    // string is 'All')
              // String newMonth = optionsList.get(0).getText();

                //}

                for (int i = 2; i < optionsList.size(); i++) {
                    WebElement element = optionsList.get(i);
                    String newMonth = element.getText();
                    if (!oldMonth.equals("All") && !newMonth.equals("All")) {



                    if (newMonth.equals(oldMonth)) {


                    // IF the string are same, nthng we need to do
                    } else if (!newMonth.equals(oldMonth)) {
                    /*
                    * If the string are not same,then i.e., considered as new
                    * Month, download the new month details
                    */
                    element.click();
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00']")).click();
                    Wait(200000);
                      //Click on File save button
                      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Button']")).click();
                      //wait time to load the options
                      Wait(20000);
                      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu']/div[2]/a")).click();
                      //fprofile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );
                      //fprofile.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled", true );
                      Wait(10000);
                    // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,
                    // TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    System.out.println(  "New month data downloaded in csv format:==>"+newMonth);
                    break; } } 
                    oldMonth = newMonth;
                } }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend to use Select instead of WebElement.

```
Select myDropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']")));
```

Second, I don't see any statements that create or read file. Can you show me the code? Personally, I prefer Apache CommonsIO.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("month.txt");
try {
    String oldMonth = IOUtils.toString(in);
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: driver.get("http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report");
WebElement mSelectElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"));List<WebElement> optionsList = mSelectElement.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
       Wait(20000);

Comment: String oldMonth = "E:\\Ashik\\wkspSelenium\\Stackcode\\Month";
       String line = null;
      String loc="E:\\Ashik\\wkspSelenium\\Stackcode\\Month";
       try {
              // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
              FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(oldMonth);

              // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
              BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
 while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {  for (int i = 2; i < optionsList.size(); i++) {

Comment: WebElement element = optionsList.get(i);
           String newMonth = element.getText();
  if (!oldMonth.equals("All") && !newMonth.equals("All")) {
  if (newMonth.equals(oldMonth)) {} else if (!newMonth.equals(oldMonth)) {
            /*
            * If the string are not same,then i.e., considered as new
            * Month, download the new month details
            */
            element.click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00']")).click();
            Wait(200000);
              //Click on File save button

Comment: Wait(10000);
           
            // TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println(  "New month data downloaded in csv format:==>"+newMonth);
            break; } } 
             oldMonth = newMonth;
               
             // String fstream=newMonth;
           } 
                  System.out.println(line);
              }   // Always close files.
              bufferedReader.close();         
          }
          catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
              System.out.println("Unable to open file '" +  oldMonth + "'"); }

Comment: }
          catch(IOException ex) {
              System.out.println("Error reading file '" + oldMonth + "'");                  
              // Or we could just do this: 
              // ex.printStackTrace();
              
              
       
 }
      
       //fstream(fstream1);
       FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(loc);

Comment: Could you tell me why do you compare !newMonth.equals(oldMonth)? If the old month is Filename and the new month is Month name, it will always break the loop at the condition 

`else if (!newMonth.equals(oldMonth)) { 
    System.out.println( "New month data downloaded in csv format:==>"+newMonth);
    break;`

Comment: hi, if it is equal no need to download any new data, requirement is only for new month data has to be downloaded.

Comment: I'm still doubt what is in the text file. However, you can use this code to append text to the file.

`try {
           Files.write(Paths.get("E:\\Ashik\\wkspSelenium\\Stackcode\\Month"), ("\n" + newMonth).getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
       } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println( "Error: " + e.getMessage());
       }`